# how to derived value of a filed from another field in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below

```
+---+------------+----------+
| ID| Date       | Amount_1 |
+---+------------+----------+
| 1 | 2016-02-02 |   100.00 |
| 1 | 2016-02-05 |   150.00 |
| 1 | 2016-02-09 |   125.00 |
| 1 | 2016-02-11 |    75.00 |
| 1 | 2016-02-19 |   -46.99 |
| 1 | 2016-02-20 |   -41.33 |
| 1 | 2016-02-29 |   -14.15 |
+---+------------+----------+
```

I want to derived another column in this table say **Amount_2** from **Amount_1**, and the value for each row of Amount_2 must be the sum of previous row and current row of **Amount_1** column.

I mean I want to get the below table.

```
+---+------------+----------+----------+
| ID| Date       | Amount_1 | Amount_2 |
+---+------------+----------+----------+
| 1 | 2016-02-02 |   100.00 |   100.00 |
| 1 | 2016-02-05 |   150.00 |   250.00 |
| 1 | 2016-02-09 |   125.00 |   375.00 |
| 1 | 2016-02-11 |    75.00 |   450.00 |
| 1 | 2016-02-19 |   -46.99 |   403.01 |
| 1 | 2016-02-20 |   -41.33 |   361.68 |
| 1 | 2016-02-29 |   -14.15 |   347.53 |
+---+------------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT  m.ID, m.Date, m.Amount_1, (@x:=  m.Amount_1 + @x) AS Amount_2
FROM    mytable m,(SELECT @x:=0) c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get by using session varable

```
SET @old_amount = 0;
SELECT ID, Date,Amount_1, (@old_amount := Amount_1 + @old_amount) AS Amount_2
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY date;
```